# Delete database entry if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that allows engineers to be added to a job by checking checkboxes which works fine.  However, I would like the user to remove an engineer by unchecking their checkbox on another form.

The table (a many to many table) has 3 columns id_ce (the primary key), call_ce (foreign key) and engineer_ce (foreign key).  I would like the form to check if a checkbox is empty and if it is check to see if there is an entry in the table with the call_ce and engineer_ce and delete it if it exists but I'm failing miserably.

This is what I have so far...

```
foreach($_POST['engineer'] as $engineer_id){
    if(!isset($_POST['engineer'])){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM calls_engineers WHERE call_ce = '$diary_id' AND engineer_ce = '$engineer_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $sql = "DELETE FROM calls_engineers WHERE engineer_ce = '$engineer_id'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
        }   
    }
}
```

I suspect the problem may be something like the checkboxes that aren't checked don't post so they aren't going through the foreach loop but I'm not sure of another way of doing it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Given your code sample, it's worth pointing out that you have an SQL injection vulnerability (you're inserting `$engineer_id` straight into your query without checking it's a valid ID beforehand).

Further to that, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you are encouraged to learn about and use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), and prepared statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put on page a hidden field with engineer ids. Say, it will be called `engineer_on_page`

Now you can

```
foreach($_POST['engineer_on_page'] as $engineer_id) {
     if(!in_array($engineer_id, $_POST['engineer'])){
          //do delete here
     }
}
```

I expect that checkboxes looks similar to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="engineer[]" value="[engineer_id]"/>
```

and hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="engineer_on_page[]" value="[engineer_id]"/>
```

Also you may specify checkbox field like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="engineer[[engineer_id]]" value="[engineer_id]"/>
```

where `[engineer_id]` is actual id (1, 2,3 etc)

In second case you may use

```
     if(!isset($_POST['engineer'][$engineer_id])){
          //do delete here
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

/* BY ROHIT BHAYAL */

$checkbox1=$_POST['stu2'];
    $chk="";

```
/* print_r($_POST['stu3']); */
$order1=$_POST['stu3'];

  if(isset($_POST['subject']))
  {

$string = implode(',', $checkbox1);

 echo $del="delete from student_subject where sub_id not in ($string)";
 mysql_query($del);

  }
  //   mysql_query($del);

 foreach ($checkbox1 as $key => $chk1)
 {  
  $chk .= $chk1.",";  

 $check="SELECT * FROM student_subject WHERE sub_id = '".$chk1."' AND form_id='".$_GET['sub']."'";
 $rs = mysql_query($check);
 $data = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
 mysql_num_rows($rs);
 if($data[0] > 1)
  {
 echo "Subject is Already Exists<br/>";

  }

else
  {

  if(isset($_POST['subject']))
  {
     $a= "sub_id='".$chk1."'";



     echo $ins = "insert into student_subject set form_id='".$_POST['stu1']."',
                                    ".$a.",
                     order_no='".$chk1."'";


  }
if (mysql_query($ins))
{
    echo "Now New subject Is Added<br/>";
}
else
{
    echo "Error adding user in database<br/>";
}
```

}
}

?>

Comment: Thanks!  `not in` is the solution